# Delete characters

Tags: java, jstl

I'm trying to use a separador between each iteration. The problem is that in the last iteration I get left with the last `//`

Example: 18000 → 32768 // 22 → 32769 //

I want: 18000 → 32768 // 22 → 32769

```
 <c:forEach var="port" items="${container.ports}">
    ${port.privatePort} &rarr; ${port.publicPort} //
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: anyone please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<c:forEach var="port" items="${container.ports}">
    <c:when test=”${not status.last}”>
        ${port.privatePort} &rarr; ${port.publicPort} //
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        ${port.privatePort} &rarr; ${port.publicPort}
    </c:otherwise>
</c:forEach>
```

Or:

```
<c:forEach var="port" items="${container.ports}">
        ${port.privatePort} &rarr; ${port.publicPort} <c:if test="${!loop.last}">//</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```